How to get page number from azure ai search index which is using split skillset?
We have created an Azure AI Search using Split Skillset to chunk our documents page wise and semantic configuration is also . Now we want to include the page number either at the end of the chunk content or as a separate index field. We have below fields in our index: parent_id, title, chunk_id, chunk.
Below are the parameters of split skillset :-
text_split_mode="pages",  
context="/document",  
maximum_page_length=2048,  
page_overlap_length=20,  

I tried to extract page number from the chunk_id : 0ffd977ce09f_aHR0cHM6Ly9hbmh@cmFpbnN0b3JhZ2VhY2NvdW50LmJsb2luS53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9maWx1dXBsb2FkLXRlc3QtaW5kZXgvQmx1ZV9aZWJyYV9MYW5kbG9yZF9JbnN1cmFuY2VfQwNjaWRlbnRhbF9EYW1hZ2VFUERTXIwMjMwNzAxLnBkZg_pages_2
ut when I checked the content of these chunks with the actual document, the page number in the chunk id is not correct. In the document the content is at 21 but in chunk it's showing 26.
How can I handle this?

there is option called imageAction = generateNormalizedImagePerPage you can configure where each page is returned as output.

You can use the imageAction configuration for extracting page number and content from each page.
By using this you will get a field name called pageNumber and you will get  content from each page as separate document in secondary index.
Below is the sample definitions.
Primary index fields.

Skillset definition - using OCR skillset the text is extracted from each page and done projection on secondary index.
{
  "name": "skillset1",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "image",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*",
          "inputs": []
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "targetName": "text"
        }
      ],
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "detectOrientation": true,
      "lineEnding": "Space"
    }
  ],
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCFB1DC59EC9ED\"",
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "desidx",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/normalized_images/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "text",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/text"
          },
          {
            "name": "pageNumber",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/pageNumber"
          },
          {
            "name": "metadata_storage_path",
            "source": "/document/metadata_storage_name"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  }
}

Whenever you given image action as generateNormalizedImagePerPage each page data will be in /document/normalized_images/* context.
Indexer
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCFB1DD13443EF\"",
  "name": "azureblob-indexer",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "ds",
  "skillsetName": "skillset1",
  "targetIndexName": "srcidx",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImagePerPage"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

Secondary index fields

Output:

Here, is the more properties of image action.

Is there any way to achieve it within split skillset that I'm using. The mode we are using is Page with maximum_page_length - 2048 and page_overlap_length - 20.

the purpose of splitskill set is to chunk the document, page_overlap_length helps not to loose data between chunks. if there is a page number content in pages, that may overlap with other pages. so try using secondary index with above approach.
